# Looping between two folders and perform operation with the fetched files

Tags: batch-file

Can anyone help me to resolve the below issue, I have two folders containing similar kind of reports (10 reports in each folder) in .xls format. I created a batch file that will extract one report from folder one and one from another folder. I am assuming that in both the folders the sequence of report is the same.

I mean `Folderx --> ReportA` then `ReportB` upto so on... Same for another folder.

After extracting the .xls file I have to compare these file using one .jar application. However, my batch file is comparing only the last reports.

Eg. `Folder-A.report10 vs Folder-B.report10`. I am expecting to compare one by one report. Means Report1 compare with Report1 then Report2 should be compared with Report2 upto so on......

Below is my code :

```
@echo off

set/p ExcelFilePath1="Path1:"
set/p ExcelFilePath2="Path2:"

set "MasterFolder1=%ExcelFilePath1%"
set "MasterFolder2=%ExcelFilePath2%"
Set LogFile=%~dpn0.txt
If exist "%LogFile%" Del "%LogFile%"

::set cdtl=0

::looploop
::for %%i IN (%MasterFolder%\*.xls) Do echo %%i
::@FOR /f "delims=" %%f IN ('dir /b /s "%MasterFolder1%\*.xls"') do set var1=%%~nxf 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR /f "delims=" %%f IN ('dir /b /s "%MasterFolder1%\*.xls"') do call set var1=%%f
echo %var1%
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /s "%MasterFolder2%\*.xls"') do call set var2=%%i 
echo %var2%
cd "C:\SunilKK-Latitude-E6430s\SunilKK\Software\PreciseExcelComparator\v1.1\PreciseExcelComparator_PEC"
call java -jar PEC.jar "%var1%" "%var2%" 0 0

::@FOR /i "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /s "%MasterFolder2%\*.xls"') do echo %%i

endlocal

pause
```

Comment: Your `for /f` do what you told them they iterate files and keep overwriting the same var. You need to insert a code block and check if the same file name (without drive:\path) exists in the other folder (`if exist "%Masterfolder2%\%%~nxf call ...`)

Comment: Hi, i am new in the batch code, i created this batch file by referring many code. could you please help to place your suggestion in my code?

Comment: Hi LotPings, I am not able to see any comments???

Comment: @LotPings, i got it why this code is not working on my side, it is because in my case under folder1 & folder2 report template is same but report name is different. Eg. Folder1 abc_rpt1 and in Folder2 xyz_rpt1 as so on.... Please advice. I am in a trouble .

Comment: I will wait for your answer.

Comment: @M.S,  i haven't seen any comment given by LotPings.. Do you know why?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't

Comment: Hello @LotPings, can you please help?